# me duplica la funcion del estado

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, switch

Es que por esta del codigo me esta duplicando la funcion que tengo.
este es el JS:

```
    if (data.rubroactivo === "t") {
        $("#rubroactivo").prop("checked", true);
        $("#rubroactivo").change();
    } else {
        $("#rubroactivo").prop("checked", false);
        $("#rubroactivo").change();
    }
```

Este es el html

```
<div class="form-group" id="contenedorEstado">
   <input type='checkbox' id="rubroactivo" data-style='toggleCheck' data-onstyle='toggleCheck' data-on='Activo' data-off='Inactivo' class='estadoToggle'  >                                   
</div>
```

Esta es la funcion en JS:

```js
function editarEstadoItems() {
  let idtiporubro = $("#idtiporubro").val();
  let rubroactivo = false;
  if ($("#rubroactivo").prop("checked") === true) {
    rubroactivo = true;
  }

  var parametros = {
    accion: AGREGAR_ITEMS,
    action: false,
    idtiporubro: idtiporubro,
    rubroactivo: rubroactivo
  };
  console.log(rubroactivo);
  var miCallback = function(callbackParams, result, estado) {
    if (estado || !result.success) {
      return;
    }
    jAlert("Se ha actualizado el estado del ID " + idtiporubro);
  };
  spinner("Registrando Documento, por favor espere...");
  utilidadesjQuery.ajax("../../modulos/configuracion/ItemsFacturacion.php", parametros, miCallback, null, this);
}
```

Y al dar click en el switch me llama esa funcion

```
$("#rubroactivo").on("change", function (event) {
    editarEstadoItems();
});
```

Tambien tengo codigo en PHP pero ya lo revise y el error creo q no esta ahi.

Y aca esta el link y el script

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../lib/jQuery/bootstrap-toggle/bootstrap4-toggle.min.js">
<script src="../../lib/jQuery/bootstrap-toggle/bootstrap4-toggle.min.js"></script>
```

me di cuenta que el error es este parte:

```
$("#rubroactivo").change();
```

ya q lo elimine y no me duplico la función.

no se como puedo cambiar eso para que haga lo mismo pero que no me duplique la funcion.

Perdon si no me explico bien.

Comment: ¿"Duplicar la función" = se dispara dos veces?

Comment: si eso es lo que pasa

Comment: Y porque la llamas a mano? no se llama sola?

Comment: pues al dar click en el switch llama la funcion

Comment: Hola Lil, ¿podrías explicar mejor como es el desarrollo de la situación? ¿que función? Por favor, podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar el resto del código e información?

Comment: claro, dame un momento

Comment: es un milagro que no tengas un loop... si al hacer el change, llamas a una funcion que llama al change, entonces lo estas llamando dos veces.. porque queres llamarlo a mano, vuelvo a preguntar, si ya se llamo solo al cambiar el valor?

Comment: ¿Por que necesitas llamar a `$("#rubroactivo").change();`? ¿Que sucede si no lo haces?

Comment: Hola Marcos, si no tengo eso no me muestra si el switch esta true o false 
PD: el true se muestra color verde y el false gris
si no tengo eso se queda gris estando true o false

Comment: Hola gbianchi, si al darle al boton hace la funcion.
perdon si te respondo mal, estoy un poco confundido

Comment: @LilGero, ¿el switch es un plugin de jQuery? Si es así, ¿podrías indicar cual y/o el link al repo? Si es un plugin puede que tenga un método para cambiar su estado.

Comment: si claro, ya lo agrego

Comment: @LilGero, si te fijas en la [documentación](https://gitbrent.github.io/bootstrap4-toggle/#api), puntualmente en "API > Methods" va a ver que provee `.bootstrapToggle('on')`  y `.bootstrapToggle('off')`. Intenta utilizar estos metodos para cambiar el estado en lugar de hacer `.prop("checked", true);` y el `.change()`. Si esto te soluciona el problema, sería bueno que crees una respuesta donde expliques los pasos que realizaste para llegar a la solución.

Comment: Cuando hagas una pregunta sobre un plugin, recuerda contar que estas usando... de otra forma, pensamos que es js puro y no podemos ver otras opciones...

Comment: Hola Marcos, si me funciono, muchas gracias.
Tambien gracias gbianchi

Comment: si señor gbianchi
, lo voy a tener en cuenta

Comment: @LilGero tal como dijo Marcos, si eso te solucionó el problema, es mejor que crees una **respuesta** (¡editar la pregunta no es responderla!) explicando lo que hiciste. Las preguntas y sus respuestas son de utilidad para todos quienes tengan un problema similar, no solo para quien redactó la pregunta. Luego, cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo [acepta](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta.

Comment: ahhh ok ya veo, no sabia, gracias por aclararme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo pude solucionar. primero cambie el JS que tenia por este

```
if (data.rubroactivo === "t") {
$("#rubroactivo").bootstrapToggle('on');
} else {   
$("#rubroactivo").bootstrapToggle('off');
}
```

Tambien tenia un error con esto

```
$("#rubroactivo").on("change", function (event) {
editarEstadoItems(); });
```

ya que tenia otro boton que se llama actualizar y tenia que agregar esa funcion ahi, para que me hiciera todo en un click y entonces borre esa parte y agregue la funcion en el boton de editar

Asi quedo el boton

```
$("#btnActualizar").on("click", function () {
    editarUsuarios();
    editarEstadoUsuario();
});
```